# Render an array of Objects in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to go through object properties  (Name for this example) and list them within easy loop in function. I have found some pretty awkward way of doing this but it doesn't seem right.

Here is what i got:

```js
const ItemsToSell = [{"Name":"Cup","Price":"99.99"},{"Name":"IPhone","Price":"99.99"},{
"Name":"Pen","Price":"99.99"}]

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const a = props.numbers;
  return (
    <ul>
      {a.map((number) =>
        <ListItem  value={ItemsToSell[number].Name} />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [0,1, 2];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I simply need a loop to go through array of objects, list needed properties and create one of many html nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply map over `ItemsToSell` array

```js
const ItemsToSell = [{"Name":"Cup","Price":"99.99"},{"Name":"IPhone","Price":"99.99"},{
"Name":"Pen","Price":"99.99"}]

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {ItemsToSell.map((obj, index) =>
        <ListItem  key={index} value={obj.Name} />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you iterate over `ItemsToSell` array? You don't have to add yet another one.

**Note**: Include `key` property while looping the elements, else you will receive an error.

```js
const ItemsToSell = [{"Name":"Cup","Price":"99.99"},{"Name":"IPhone","Price":"99.99"},{
"Name":"Pen","Price":"99.99"}]

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {ItemsToSell.map((elem, index) =>
        <ListItem value={elem.Name} key={index} />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what i needed.