# Loop through simple array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not using JSX. Is this a problem? Is this considered bad practice?

```
var links = [
  { endpoint: '/america' },
  { endpoint: '/canada' },
  { endpoint: '/norway' },
  { endpoint: '/bahamas' }
];

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul>
          const listItems = links.map((link) =>
            <li key={link.endpoint}>{link.endpoint}</li> 
          );
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Based on the basic list component section of the react docs, it seems like I should be able to print the contents of an array, the way I'm doing it inside my `<ul></ul>`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Is the problem that I am using an array of objects? The docs are using a simple array. I'd appreciate a push into the right direction.

Comment: Shouldn't `const listItems` be wrapped inside `{}`? Also can you explain *I am not using JSX*?/

Comment: `return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul>
          const listItems = links.map((link) =>
            <li key={link.endpoint}>{link.endpoint}</li> 
          );
        </ul>
      </div>
    );` is using JSX, and you can't have const inside it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render an array in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078848/render-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I thought to use JSX, you need to save your files as .jsx, which gives you access to different functionality. Also, I've noticed in  "my understanding" of JSX components are declared differently, and separated by a comma. I could be wrong about this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The issue is that your syntax is invalid, you should have something like this :

```
var links = [
  { endpoint: '/america' },
  { endpoint: '/canada' },
  { endpoint: '/norway' },
  { endpoint: '/bahamas' }
];

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const listItems = links.map((link) =>
        <li key={link.endpoint}>{link.endpoint}</li> 
    );
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks. Is there anyway to use old `forEach` here?

Comment: @Volatil3 Yeah, i assume you could do that, however i find Array.prototype.map easier to use: 

    `const listItems = []; links.forEach(function (link) { listItems.push(<li>${link.endpoint}</li>); });`

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    class Navigation extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="navigation">
            <ul>
              {
                links.map(link =>
                  <li key={link.endpoint}>{link.endpoint}</li> 
                )
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: This worked as well, just had to remove the semi colon after the closing `map();` parentheses. Thanks