# How do you map an array of objects within an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to map an array of objects within an object and I can't seem to get it working. My code's goal is to map and then display the content within the "menu" array.

**Here is the structure of the object** (logged to console from a state).

```
Object {
  "id": 1,
  "img": "https://cuisinederue.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Greg2.png",
  "menu": Array [
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Greg's Burger",
      "price": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Poutine double cheese bacon",
      "price": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Cône de poulet pop corn et frites maison",
      "price": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Grilled cheese Philly steak",
      "price": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Poutine Philly cheese steak",
      "price": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "description": "Les prix sont défini à la tête du client",
      "name": "Boulette de mac'n'cheese",
      "price": 1,
    },
  ],
  "name": "Greg's dinner",
  "type": "SOUTHERN COMFORT",
}
```

**And here is the code that I'm trying to get to work:** (specifically the `details.menu.map` part)

```
const Details = ({navigation, idTruck}) =>{
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [detailsDone, setDetailsDone] = useState(false);

  const getDetails = () => {  
    fetch("https://foodtrack-420kbc-lg.herokuapp.com/trucks/1").then(res => res.json()).then(resp => setDetails(resp));
  }

  if(!detailsDone)
  {
    getDetails();
    setDetailsDone(true);
  }
  console.log(details);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header title='Details'></Header>
      <Image name="logo" style={styles.detailsImage} source={{uri: details.img}}></Image>
      <Text name="nom">{details.name}</Text>
      <Text name="style">{details.type}</Text>


        {


          details.menu.map(({description, name, price}) => 
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text name="nom">{name}</Text>
              <Text name="prix">{price}</Text>
              <Text name="desc">{description}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        }

    </View>
  )
}
```

**The error I am getting is:** `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'details.menu.map'`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change like this `details.menu.map((detail) =>`  and `<Text name="nom">{detail.name}</Text>`

Comment: @sibabratswain sadly I still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Did you change for price and description like name right?

Comment: @sibabratswain yes, I'm still getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'details.menu.map'

Comment: Check with this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45857744/9739044

Comment: @sibabratswain I will, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have big problem in controlling JS asynchronous. Please try to understand it first before you start to study reactJS. Some async functions: setTimeout, setInterval, Ajax (call api), here is small [tut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)  . From this point, you don't need to use detailsDone state.
2. High performance when use useEffect for calling api only 1 time.

```js
const initValue = {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    type: "",
    img: "",
    menu: []
}
const [details, setDetails] = useState(initValue); // init value is object, not array

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://foodtrack-420kbc-lg.herokuapp.com/trucks/1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resp => setDetails(resp));
}, []); // ensure call api run 1 time when this component render.
```

Comment: You're right that my code isn't optimized however this didn't solve my problem sadly. Thanks for the tips and I will look into better learning async JS!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're trying to map over `details.menu`, but when the component loads initially, `details` is an empty array, which does not have property `menu`.

One workaround would be to conditionally render something else (like a loading indicator) until the data is set into component state.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a combination of this and the top answer!