# How to map local array in React card component using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have Interfaces like this:

```
interface INewsProps {
  newsType: string;
  data: INewsContentProps[];
}

interface INewsContentProps {
  title: string;
  newsContent: string;
}
```

My array is this:

```
  export const newsList: INewsContentProps[] = [
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum',
    newsContent: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis hendrerit dui ac accumsan consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum2',
    newsContent: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis hendrerit dui ac accumsan consequat.'
  }
];
```

I need to get properties from the array to show here:

```
export const NewsCard = () => {
  return (
     <div>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography>
                {props.title} 
              </Typography>
               <Typography>
                {props.newsContent} 
              </Typography>
              <ContextMenu />
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
     </div>
  );
};
```

I am new in React and also in TypeScript so I will be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Note that JSON is a text format, like XML or CSV. The list you show is just an array of objects. Nothing JSON about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through simple array of objects in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857698/loop-through-simple-array-of-objects-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure if you want a card per entry in your array but you want to make use of Array's `map()` function like so:

```
export const NewsCard = (newsItem) => {
  return (
     <div>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography>
                {newsItem.title} 
              </Typography>
               <Typography>
                {newsItem.newsContent} 
              </Typography>
              <ContextMenu />
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
     </div>
  );
};

return newsList.map(newsItem => NewsCard(newsItem));
```

This will map each element in your array to a `<Card>` element where each entry in the array is accessed by `newsItem`. I hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Glad this is what you’re looking for - I can’t immediately see why you’re getting that error so I might need more code to aid with that! It sounds like your news card function is not returning any JSX as expected?

Comment: Glad you got it working Fresh! Don’t forget to mark the answer as correct and upvote it!

Answer (score 2):

To render multiple elements you can use `.map()` function for arrays. Your NewsCard component should accept an argument as props to access `props.title` and `props.newsContent`.

```
return newsList.map((content, ix) => (
    <NewsCard
      key={ix + content.title}
      title={content.title}
      newsContent={content.newsContent}
    />
  ));
```

You can refer this working demo on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-star-7u4rq?file=/src/App.tsx:609-776)

Answer (score 2):

You can use NewsCard as component.
Lets say that

```
export const NewsCard = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography>
                {props.title} 
              </Typography>
               <Typography>
                {props.newsContent} 
              </Typography>
              <ContextMenu />
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
     </div>
  );
};
```

Now you have a component called NewsCard that taks props of type

```
{ title: string, newsContent: string | any }
```

Now you have a list of

```
{
    title: 'Lorem ipsum',
    newsContent: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis hendrerit dui ac accumsan consequat.'
}
```

Lets say that you using App component to show the list of cards

```
function App(){

return (
    <>
    {newsList.map((cardListItem, index)=> <NewsCard key={`card-${index}`} title={cardListItem.title} newsContent={cardListItem.newsContent} /> )}
    </>
    );
}
```

assuming that NewsCard is in the same file otherwise you need to import it.

For more info please visit the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)