# Render array data in class i react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to make a card.

For that I need to make 3 components.

- First for `Card Header`
- Second for `Card Description` and
- Third for main Card that will give values to both components.

In my Card class I want to display the array data. I have no idea how to do that.

I believe I should use `map()` but I do not understand how.

My structure should be like `Card header1` with `Card description1` then `Card header2` with `Card description2`.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React Cards</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen1.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/jsx">
    class Header extends React.Component { render () { return (
    <div className='t1'>
      <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
    </div>
    ) } } class CardDesc extends React.Component { render () { return (
    <div className='t2' id='this.props.id'>{this.props.text}</div>
    ) } } class Card extends React.Component { render () { return (
    <div className='t3'>
      <Header text="this.props.head" />
      <CardDesc text="this.props.des" />
    </div>
    ) } } var cardContent = [ {head:'Header one',des:'000'}, {head:'Header two',des:'001'},
    {head:'Header three',des:'002'}, {head:'Header four',des:'004'}, {head:'Header
    five',des:'005'}, {head:'Header six',des:'006'} ]; ReactDOM.render(

    <Card />, document.getElementById('root'))
  </script>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render an array in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078848/render-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass a variable as props, don't use quotes, instead use `{}`, so change:

```
<Header text="this.props.head"/>
<CardDesc text="this.props.des" />
```

To:

```
<Header text={this.props.head}/>
<CardDesc text={this.props.des} />
```

Now, you can simply render your cards like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {cardContent.map(cardItem => <Card head={cardItem.head} des={cardItem.des} />)}
  </div>
, document.getElementById('root'))
```

As you can see, a root element (div in this case) is required for the render function.

Another method would be to create a `CardList` component, and render that, instead of having the map in `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I didn't understand the logic in ReactDOM.render, as i don't know how map() works.

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple rendering to the root element is bad idea, you can try create new component like App or whatever, end map your card components into it.
[Look at this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s1ck9r)